# Unique BooleanField value in Django?

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Suppose my models.py is like so:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField()
```

I want only one of my `Character` instances to have `is_the_chosen_one == True` and all others to have `is_the_chosen_one == False` . How can I best ensure this uniqueness constraint is respected?

Top marks to answers that take into account the importance of respecting the constraint at the database, model and (admin) form levels!

Comment: Good question. I'm also curious if its possible to set up such a constraint. I know that if you simply made it a unique constraint you'll end up with only two possible rows in your database ;-)

Comment: Not necessarily: if you use a NullBooleanField, then you should be able to have: (a True, a False, any number of NULLs).

Comment: According to [my research](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39374169/2996101), [@semente](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12269037/2996101) answer,  takes into account the importance of respecting the constraint at the database, model and (admin) form levels while it provides a great solution even for a ```through``` table of ```ManyToManyField``` that needs a ```unique_together``` constraint.

Answer (score 76):

Whenever I've needed to accomplish this task, what I've done is override the save method for the model and have it check if any other model has the flag already set (and turn it off).

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_the_chosen_one:
            try:
                temp = Character.objects.get(is_the_chosen_one=True)
                if self != temp:
                    temp.is_the_chosen_one = False
                    temp.save()
            except Character.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'd just change
    'def save(self):'
to:
    'def save(self, *args, **kwargs):'

Comment: I tried to edit this to change `save(self)` to `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` but the edit was rejected. Could any of the reviewers take time to explain why - since this would seem to be consistent with Django best practice.

Comment: I tried editing to remove the need for try/except and to make the process more efficient but it was rejected.. Instead of `get()`ing the Character object and then `save()`ing it again, you just need to filter and update, which produces just one SQL query and helps keep the DB consistent:
`if self.is_the_chosen_one:` <newline>
`Character.objects.filter(is_the_chosen_one=True).update(is_the_chosen_one=False)` <newline>
`super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I cannot suggest any better method to accomplish that task but i want to say that, don't ever trust save or clean methods if you are running a web application which you might take a few of requests to an endpoint at very same moment. You still must implement a safer way maybe on database level.

Comment: There is a better answer below. Ellis Percival's answer uses `transaction.atomic` which is important here. It is also more efficient using a single query.

Comment: Don’t forget to provide a custom `QuerySet` with overridden `update` method to prevent from updating multiple objects’ `is_the_chosen_one` to `True` in one go.

Answer (score 50):

I'd override the save method of the model and if you've set the boolean to True, make sure all others are set to False.

```
from django.db import transaction

class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_the_chosen_one:
            return super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        with transaction.atomic():
            Character.objects.filter(
                is_the_chosen_one=True).update(is_the_chosen_one=False)
            return super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried editing the similar answer by Adam, but it was rejected for changing too much of the original answer. This way is more succinct and efficient as the checking of other entries is done in a single query.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but I would suggest wrapping `save` into a `@transaction.atomic` transaction. Because it could happen that you remove all flags, but then saving fails and you end up with all characters not chosen.

Comment: Thank you for saying so. You are absolutely right and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Mitar `@transaction.atomic` also protects from race condition.

Comment: Best solution among all!

Comment: Regarding transaction.atomic I used the context manager instead of a decorator. I see no reason to use atomic transaction on every model save as this only matters if the boolean field is true. I suggest using `with transaction.atomic:` inside the if statement along with saving inside the if. Then adding an else block and also saving in the else block.

Comment: @alexbhandari nice spot! I've updated the answer. How does that look to you?

Answer (score 44):

It is simpler to add this kind of constraint to your model
after Django version 2.2. You can directly use `UniqueConstraint.condition`. [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.condition)

Just override your models `class Meta` like this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(fields=['is_the_chosen_one'], condition=Q(is_the_chosen_one=True), name='unique_is_the_chosen_one')
    ]
```

Comment: This is simple and concise. Great! Thanks.

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: This is a neat solution. Unfortunately, not so good if you're using MySQL because MySQL does not support unique constraints with conditions.

Answer (score 31):

Instead of using custom model cleaning/saving, I created a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) overriding the `pre_save` method on `django.db.models.BooleanField`. Instead of raising an error if another field was `True`, I made all other fields `False` if it was `True`. Also instead of raising an error if the field was `False` and no other field was `True`, I saved it the field as `True`

**fields.py**

```py
from django.db.models import BooleanField


class UniqueBooleanField(BooleanField):
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        objects = model_instance.__class__.objects
        # If True then set all others as False
        if getattr(model_instance, self.attname):
            objects.update(**{self.attname: False})
        # If no true object exists that isnt saved model, save as True
        elif not objects.exclude(id=model_instance.id)\
                        .filter(**{self.attname: True}):
            return True
        return getattr(model_instance, self.attname)

# To use with South
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^project\.apps\.fields\.UniqueBooleanField"])
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

from project.apps.fields import UniqueBooleanField


class UniqueBooleanModel(models.Model):
    unique_boolean = UniqueBooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.unique_boolean)
```

Comment: This looks far more clean than the other methods

Comment: I like this solution as well, although it seems potentially dangerous to have the objects.update set all other objects to False in the case where the models UniqueBoolean is True. Would be even better if the UniqueBooleanField took an optional argument to indicate whether the other objects should be set to False or if an error should be raised (the other sensible alternative).  

Also, given your comment in the elif, where you want to set the attribute to true, I think you should change  
 `Return True` to `setattr(model_instance, self.attname, True)`

Comment: UniqueBooleanField isn't really unique since you can have as many False values as you want. Not sure what a better name would be... OneTrueBooleanField? What I really want is to be able to scope this in combination with a foreign key so that I could have a BooleanField that was only allowed to be True once per relationship (e.g. a CreditCard has a "primary" field and a FK to User and the User/Primary combination is True once per use). For that case I think Adam's answer overriding save will be more straightforward for me.

Comment: It should be noted that this method allows you end up in a state with no rows set as `true` if you delete the only `true` row.

Answer (score 12):

The following solution is a little bit ugly but might work:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    is_the_chosen_one = models.NullBooleanField(default=None, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_the_chosen_one is False:
            self.is_the_chosen_one = None
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you set is_the_chosen_one to False or None it will be always NULL. You can have NULL as much as you want, but you can only have one True.

Comment: The first solution I thought of also. NULL is always unique so you can always have a column with more than one NULL.

Answer (score 12):

Trying to make ends meet with the answers here, I find that some of them address the same issue successfully and each one is suitable in different situations:

I would choose:

- [@semente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12269037/2996101): Respects the constraint at the database, model and admin form levels while it overrides Django ORM the least possible. Moreover it can be used inside a  `through` table  of a `ManyToManyField` in a`unique_together` situation.

  ```
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=None, unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.is_the_chosen_one is False:
                self.is_the_chosen_one = None
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

  **Update**: `NullBooleanField` will be [deprecated](https://djangodoctor.medium.com/nullbooleanfield-is-dead-7d3fc286ed6e) by [Django-4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/4.0/#features-deprecated-in-4-0), for `BooleanField(null=True)`.
- [@Ellis Percival](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23513962/2996101): Hits the database only one extra time and accepts the current entry as the chosen one. Clean and elegant.

  ```
    from django.db import transaction

    class Character(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_the_chosen_one:
            # The use of return is explained in the comments
            return super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  
        with transaction.atomic():
            Character.objects.filter(
                is_the_chosen_one=True).update(is_the_chosen_one=False)
            # The use of return is explained in the comments
            return super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

Other solutions not suitable for my case but viable:

[@nemocorp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632430/2996101) is overriding the `clean` method to perform a validation. However, it does not report back which model is "the one" and this is not user friendly. Despite that, it is a very nice approach especially if someone does not intend to be as aggressive as @Flyte.

[@saul.shanabrook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752305/2996101) and [@Thierry J.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340608/2996101) would create a custom field which would either change any other "is_the_one" entry to `False` or raise a `ValidationError`. I am just reluctant to impement new features to my Django installation unless it is absoletuly necessary.

[@daigorocub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35585565/2996101): Uses Django signals. I find it a unique approach and gives a hint of how to use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). However I am not sure whether this is a -strictly speaking- "proper" use of signals since I cannot consider this procedure as part of a "decoupled application".

Comment: Thanks for the review! I've updated my answer a little, based on one of the comments, in case you want to update your code here too.

Comment: @EllisPercival Thank you for the hint! I updated the code accordingly. Bear in mind though that [models.Model.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) does not return something.

Comment: That's fine. It's mostly just to save having the first return on its own line. Your version is actually incorrect, as it doesn't include the .save() in the atomic transaction. Plus, it should be 'with transaction.atomic():' instead.

Comment: @EllisPercival OK, thank you! Indeed, we need everything rolled back, should the `save()` operation fails!

Answer (score 7):

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_the_chosen_one:
            qs = Character.objects.filter(is_the_chosen_one=True)
            if self.pk:
                qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            if qs.count() != 0:
                # choose ONE of the next two lines
                self.is_the_chosen_one = False # keep the existing "chosen one"
                #qs.update(is_the_chosen_one=False) # make this obj "the chosen one"
        super(Character, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class CharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Character

    # if you want to use the new obj as the chosen one and remove others, then
    # be sure to use the second line in the model save() above and DO NOT USE
    # the following clean method
    def clean_is_the_chosen_one(self):
        chosen = self.cleaned_data.get('is_the_chosen_one')
        if chosen:
            qs = Character.objects.filter(is_the_chosen_one=True)
            if self.instance.pk:
                qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
            if qs.count() != 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("A Chosen One already exists! You will pay for your insolence!")
        return chosen
```

You can use the above form for admin as well, just use

```
class CharacterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CharacterForm
admin.site.register(Character, CharacterAdmin)
```

Answer (score 6):

And that's all.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.default_dp:
        DownloadPageOrder.objects.all().update(**{'default_dp': False})
    super(DownloadPageOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: straight forward, simple and works

Answer (score 5):

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField()

    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        c = Character.objects.filter(is_the_chosen_one__exact=True)  
        if c and self.is_the_chosen:
            raise ValidationError("The chosen one is already here! Too late")
```

Doing this made the validation available in the basic admin form

Answer (score 3):

Using a similar approach as Saul, but slightly different purpose:

```
class TrueUniqueBooleanField(BooleanField):

    def __init__(self, unique_for=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unique_for = unique_for
        super(BooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = super(TrueUniqueBooleanField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)

        objects = model_instance.__class__.objects

        if self.unique_for:
            objects = objects.filter(**{self.unique_for: getattr(model_instance, self.unique_for)})

        if value and objects.exclude(id=model_instance.id).filter(**{self.attname: True}):
            msg = 'Only one instance of {} can have its field {} set to True'.format(model_instance.__class__, self.attname)
            if self.unique_for:
                msg += ' for each different {}'.format(self.unique_for)
            raise ValidationError(msg)

        return value
```

This implementation will raise a `ValidationError` when attempting to save another record with a value of True.

Also, I have added the `unique_for` argument which can be set to any other field in the model, to check true-uniqueness only for records with the same value, such as:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    main = TrueUniqueBooleanField(unique_for='user', default=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do I get points for answering my question?

problem was it was finding itself in the loop, fixed by:

```
    # is this the testimonial image, if so, unselect other images
    if self.testimonial_image is True:
        others = Photograph.objects.filter(project=self.project).filter(testimonial_image=True)
        pdb.set_trace()
        for o in others:
            if o != self: ### important line
                o.testimonial_image = False
                o.save()
```

Comment: No, no points for answering your own question and accepting that answer. However, there are points to be made if somebody upvotes your answer. :)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to answer your own question [here instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072349/how-to-enforce-that-object-is-only-with-a-boolean-attr-set-to-true)? Basically you and @sampablokuper had the same question

Answer (score 2):

I tried some of these solutions, and ended up with another one, just for the sake of code shortness (don't have to override forms or save method).
For this to work, the field can't be unique in it's definition but the signal makes sure that happens.

```
# making default_number True unique
@receiver(post_save, sender=Character)
def unique_is_the_chosen_one(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_the_chosen_one:
        Character.objects.all().exclude(pk=instance.pk).update(is_the_chosen_one=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

2020 update to make things less complicated for beginners:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_the_chosen_one = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=False)

    def save(self):
         if self.is_the_chosen_one == True:
              items = Character.objects.filter(is_the_chosen_one = True)
              for x in items:
                   x.is_the_chosen_one = False
                   x.save()
         super().save()
```

Of course, if you want the unique boolean to be False, you would just swap every instance of True with False and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing a solution which overwrites model.save()*, I ran into the issue of Django Admin raising an error before hitting model.save(). The cause seems to be Admin calling model.clean() (or perhaps model.full_clean(), I didn't investigate too carefully) before calling model.save(). model.clean() in turn calls model.validate_unique() which raises a ValidationError before my custom save method can take care of the unique violation. To solve this I overwrote model.validate_unique() as follows:

```
    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        try:
            super().validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
        except ValidationError as e:
            validation_errors = e.error_dict
            try:
                list_validation_errors = validation_errors["is_the_chosen_one"]
                for validation_error in list_validation_errors:
                    if validation_error.code == "unique":
                        list_validation_errors.remove(validation_error)
                if not list_validation_errors:
                    validation_errors.pop(key)
            except KeyError:
                continue
            if e.error_dict:
                raise e
```

* the same would be true for a signal solution using pre_save, as pre_save is also not sent before .validate_unique is called