# how to enforce that object is only with a boolean attr set to true?

Tags: django, django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique BooleanField value in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455126/unique-booleanfield-value-in-django)

on a photograph model i want to choose it as the photograph that is the cover image for a gallery on a page that lists multiple galleries.

i wrote the following code, but it looks like ive created a loop

```
class Photograph(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photographs/")
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to="photographs/", blank=True, help_text="Ignore this field, it will autopopulate")
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False, help_text="Ignore this field, it will autopopulate")
    portfolio_image = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Do you want this image to appear as the portfolio image?")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def save(self):
    # get filename for use later
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
    self.filename = slugify(filename)
    self.thumbnail = filename+"-t.jpg"

    # is this the testimonial image, if so, unselect other images
    if self.testimonial_image is True:
        others = Photograph.objects.filter(project=self.project).filter(testimonial_image=True)
        pdb.set_trace()
        for o in others:
            o.testimonial_image = False
            o.save()
```

whats heppening is

- upload an image, set it to
  portfolio_image
- code runs through and hits the if statement
- populates others, gets to o.save() and ends up running exactly the same
  code as i've defined.

looped!

how do i get round this?

Comment: where is `testimonial_image` defined?

Comment: also, you should either set `thumb` and `filename` to `editable=False` in the model, or exclude them from your form instead of stating to the user that they will be autopopulated

Comment: they're in for testing purposes. gonna edit the question now, deleted the wrong one, ive got a testimonial and a portflio image for this model

Answer (score 2):

I think you should store `testimonial_image` somewhere else, and it should equal `id` of needed `Photograph` object.

Comment: good idea. Instead of giving each photo a data point in the db, even though most of them will be false anyway, you could have a small table with just 2 columns, a foreign key to album, and a foreign key to the cover shot.

Comment: i'd rather the user be able to upload an image and set the attr at the time.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should store this flag for any photo. Store it in another table (as j_syk suggests, for example), and set it in `save()`. That's what you want.