# Django model booleanfield only 1 True for table

Tags: django

I have the model

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    isActive = model.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = model.ForeignKey('Owner')
```

I want to enforce that only one PhoneNumber is active so if the user, when creating or editing a 'not active' PhoneNumber, accidentally sets it to 'active' and there is another 'active' PhoneNumber already the form should not submit and a clear error will get displayed to change the 'active' field to False and error text "Please deactivate the old active PhoneNumber before assigning a new active PhoneNumber"

How do I do this? In which validation method in which class do I check this easily ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you also have a ForeignKey to the user in this model?

Comment: Yes sorry. I will update the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackoverflow: Unique BooleanField value in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455126/unique-booleanfield-value-in-django)

Answer (score 5):

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    isActive = models.NullBooleanField(default=None, unique=True)
    owner = model.ForeignKey('Owner')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isActive is False:
            self.isActive = None
        super(PhoneNumber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you provide little description about your code. Why you have used `NullBooleanField` ?

Answer (score 0):

Often validation like this can be done automatically by defining `unique_together` in the model's Meta class, but here that will not work as you could possibly have many inactive phone numbers for each user. So you will need custom validation. One way to do that will be in the `clean` method of the model itself, which is called when the form is validated.

```
def clean(self):
    if self.isActive:
        active = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(isActive=True, owner=self.owner)
        if self.pk:
            active = active.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        if active.exists():
            raise ValidationError("An active phone number already exists for this user")
```

Comment: What does " if self.pk:
            active = active.exclude(pk=self.pk)" do ?

Comment: Makes sure you're not finding the current instance of Phone Number, if it has previously been saved.

Comment: Can't you add another model for the active number, with one-to-one relation to owner?  This will enforce this rule (my answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is not one way to do it. But I can suggest doing it in the model itself and override `save` method like the following:

```
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    isActive = model.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner')
    phone_number = odels.CharField(max_length=50)

     class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'phone_number',)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id: # to ensure that the object is being updated and is not a new one
             if not self.isActive:
                  check_active_uniquniess = self._meta.model.objects.filter(user = self.user).exclude(id=self.id).count()
                  if check_active_uniquniess:
                         raise ValidationError("Please deactivate the old active PhoneNumber before assigning a new active PhoneNumber")
        super(PhoneNumber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can also suggest to override the clean method in ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    phone_number = model.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = model.ForeignKey('Owner')

class ActivePhoneNumber(models.Model):

    active_phone_number = model.ForeignKey(PhoneNumber)
    owner = model.OneToOneField(Owner)
```

PhoneNumber can hold multiple numbers per owner, where ActivePhoneNumber only one number per owner. This will enforce the one active number per user rule in the model level.

You will still need to provide a form to replace active number. Something like:

```
owner=self.request.user
new_number = PhoneNumber(owner=owner,phone_number="foobar")
# or new_number = owner.phone_number_set.get(phone_number="foobar")
new_number.save()
owner.active_phone_number.delete()
new_active = ActivePhoneNumber(owner=owner,active_phone_number=new_number)
new_active.save()
```

Note: If one PhoneNumber can be used by only one owner, then set:

```
active_phone_number = model.OneToOneField(PhoneNumber)
```