# Django referencing a specific object in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, related_name="articles", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to add a `favorite_article` field to my `Reporter` model that will reference a specific `Article` from `reporter.articles`.

One option is put the information into the `Article` model instead:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, related_name="articles", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField()
```

But this doesn't seem like a very clean solution. Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or do you have any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: @HenryWoody I added a possible method that I've considered. I'm hoping that there is a cleaner/better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you've suggested will work, however in its current form it allows for multiple Articles to be the favorite of one Reporter. With a bit of extra processing you can ensure that only one (at most) Article per Reporter is the favorite.

Making a few modifications to a couple of the answers to the question [Unique BooleanField value in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455126/unique-booleanfield-value-in-django) we can restrict one `True` value per Reporter rather than one `True` value for the entire Article model. The approach is to check for other favorite Articles for the same Reporter and set them to not be favorites when saving an instance (rather than using a validation restriction).

I'd also suggest using a single transaction in the `save` method so that if saving the instance fails the other instances are not modified.

Here's an example:

```
from django.db import transaction

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, related_name="articles", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            if self.is_favorite:
                reporter_id = self.reporter.id if self.reporter is not None else self.reporter_id
                other_favorites = Article.objects.filter(is_favorite=True, reporter_id=reporter_id)
                if self.pk is not None: # is None when creating a new instance
                    other_favorites.exclude(pk=self.pk)
                other_favorites.update(is_favorite=False)
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've also changed the approach to use a `filter` rather than a `get` just in case.

Then to get the favorite article for a `reporter`, you can use:

```
try:
    favorite_article = reporter.articles.get(is_favorite=True)
except Article.DoesNotExist:
    favorite_article = None
```

which you could wrap into a method/property of the Reporter class.

Comment: Thanks @Henry Woody, this works, but I was hoping for something that kept the `favorite_article` field tied to the reporter, so that it can be directly referenced, rather than having to search through (potentially many) articles to find the one marked as the favorite.

Comment: @USS1994 You can retrieve the favorited article with `reporter.articles.get(is_favorite=True)` (or just `filter`) so you don't have to search through. Also you should wrap this in a `try`/`except` in case the reporter doesn't have a favorited article. Does that approach work for you?